# Connect to MariaDB with LibreOffice 5.2 (edits are not possible)

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, synology, libreoffice-base

I installed MariaDB and phpMyAdmin on my Synology at work and created a database. I was able to create the first fields with LO Base, which means that the JDBC-connector is working. The user hast % as location and I can edit everything from my machine with IntelliJ IDEA.

But: when I try to create a view with LO Base I get: **The field names from 'database. Tables' could not be retrieved**

I can see the data/rows in LO Base but I am **not** able to edit it. Which is possible in IDEA (add rows, modify content, etc.). I use the same credentials.

I do have the newest JDBC-driver/connector from the mysql-website and the connection-test worked. Is there a known issue with the latest release of base? I was able to do this in LO 4.X.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop the synology OS is up to date, so as the packages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth I was unable to reproduce your issue using the setup I have, namely: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MariaDB server 10.1.13, LibreOffice Base 5.1.4.2, and MariaDB Java client 1.5.2 (org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver). Everything seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I found the issue: underscores in the database name. At least everything works if I remove it. Really odd, the docs (of mariaDB) even recomend using them.

Comment: Confirmed that underscores produce this error: "Could not connect: Unknown database 'foo_bar'"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem: my database had underscores in the name. Removing them solved the issue.